# Problem in produce function() in R with arguments in group_by()

Tags: r, function, dplyr

This is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
sums <- function(x, y) {
        
        if(nargs() < 2){  
               a <-  mtcars %>% group_by(.$x) %>% summarise(tot = sum(disp))}
        
        else{
               a <-  mtcars  %>% group_by(.$x,.$y) %>% summarise(tot= sum(disp))
        }
        
        a
}

sums(cyl)

sums(cyl,gear)
```

Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are passing unquoted arguments, use curly-curly operator (`{{}}`)

```
sums <- function(x, y) {
    
    if(nargs() < 2){  
           a <-  mtcars %>% 
                   group_by({{x}}) %>%
                   summarise(tot = sum(disp))
          } else{
           a <-  mtcars  %>% 
                   group_by({{x}},{{y}}) %>% 
                   summarise(tot= sum(disp))
      }
    
    a
   }
```